# C++ COM port Opening, Reading and Writing

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port, createfile

I am trying to open a COM port using Win32's CreateFile function. I have read docs at MSDN as well as on several forums on how to do that but no matter what I do I still get Error code #2 (port does not exist). The code I currently have is:

```
m_hCom = CreateFile(
    "\\.\COM10",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    0,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL
);
if (m_hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    int error = GetLastError();
    return FALSE;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Please ignore my bad code formatting, already wasted 15 minutes on it.

Comment: Do you actually have 10 COM ports on your system?

Comment: BTW, to nitpick, the C++ language does not have a `createFile` function.  Writing to COM ports is platform specific; some platforms may not have a COM port.

Comment: @Ferruccio, Yes I have 10 COM ports, I can connect to COM10 using hyperterminal.

Comment: @Ferruccio: A serial port named `COM10` does not necessarily mean the computer actually has 10 ports. I can configure what number is assigned to what COM port, so it's possible to have only 3 serial ports attached but have them named `COM12`, `COM5`, and `COM37` for example. Or perhaps some installed COM ports may not actually be physical serial ports.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting in some extra slashes like this:

"\\\\.\\COM10"

Because the backslash is a special character you have to insert two for each one you want in your string.

Comment: I tried using slashes but I am still receiving same error, on other forums people say that this solution works on visual studio 2008, but for me it is not working on visual studio 2010, some thing about unicode or character encoding.

Comment: @Architact: It should not be dependent on the version of Visual Studio since `CreateFile()` is implemented by the operating system. Check to see if you actually have a serial port called `COM10` installed, plugged-in and working correctly.

Comment: @Architact If it is a matter of unicode vs. ANSI you should say `L"\\\\.\\COM10"`

Comment: @ln silico, how can check if my machine actually have a serial port called `COM10`?

Comment: use the Device Manager (on WinXP the magic way to get there is My Computer -> right-click -> Manage -> Device Manager -> Ports (COM & LPT) which will show the ports present on the system).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing some temporary code that iterates or lists the available COM ports.

There is a great chance that your COM port naming is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the same code you are trying to write not long ago.  If you say there is a 10th COM port then it should work as long as you have the extra slashes.  You can trying going the projects property window and changing the Character Set to multibyte characters.  Good luck!

Comment: This one sounds like a nice solution, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CreateFile(L"COM1", ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code in a C++ Project and if the Comport let's say COMPORT 4 is taken by let's say TeraTerm it sends back an error otherwise it opens up the port.

HANDLE hComm;
    hComm = CreateFile(
        L"\\.\COM4",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL
        );
    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("The Comport is closed or taken by another hardware/software!\n\r");
    }