# Cannot open COM port in C++ Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, serial-port

I'm trying to open a COM port with visual studio 2010. I get an `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` after `CreateFile`. The COM port 1 is reachable, an external software could connect it.

Here is my code :

```
  portCom = "\\\\.\\COM1";
  HANDLE hCom = CreateFile(portCom,
                      GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
                      0,                          /* no share  */
                      NULL,                       /* no security */
                      OPEN_EXISTING,
                      0,                          /* no threads */
                      NULL);                      /* no templates */

  if(hCom==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    printf("unable to open portCom\n");
    return(1);
  }
```

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` say after the call? Are you sure the ports not in use?

Comment: Nothing... I'm not sure about the port, I wanted to find a tool that could give me access to the port settings, like security, etc...

Comment: GetLastError() returns *something*.  Put "@err" in a watch expression.  Actually having COM1 on a machine is very rare these days, look in Device Manager.

Comment: DWORD lastErrorMessage = GetLastError(); printf(" Last Error : %lu ", lastErrorMessage);   I got " Last Error : 2"...

Comment: Well that's ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. As Hans said, double check that COM1 actually exists

Comment: Have you tried `COM1:` ?

Comment: Well, "COM1:" worked perfectly. Thanks a lot Harry ;) @Alex K : in device manager COM1 was detected. This is why I became crazy. And I could print the error, except a number like 5347320182865920, 'cause std::cout wasn't detected as existing in VS (and printf could display the error). So yes I also thought the COM1 wasn't found but not for a syntax error !

Comment: @Mr.Starck please post answer for your question, in case anyone finds it usefull.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ COM port Opening, Reading and Writing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955440/c-com-port-opening-reading-and-writing)

Comment: @jb. Sorry I had totally forgotten ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the `\\\\` style encoding for COM ports above 9. Try just specifying `COM1`.

Comment: I've tried with "\\COM1", "COM1", ".COM1" and ".\\COM1" ! Nothing

Comment: Hmm, strange. In the printer control panel do you have a generic printer set up? Is so, see if it's pointing to COM1.

Comment: There is a printer but it is on IP port. I'm gonna look for a tool display serial ports informations

Comment: I've tried `COM1` and `\\\\.\\COM1` on my PC and both work. If you go to the "Device Manager"  and look at the "Ports" section does it list COM1 ?

Comment: Yes. I had tried to desactivate it and reactive. You say that you tried exactly with this piece of code ?

Comment: @Mr.Starck Why are you spending all this time trying random names instead of just calling `GetLastError` to find out what the problem is?

Comment: @Mr.Starck - yes, I pasted in your code and it worked :-) Try calling `GetLastError` and adding the error code to the question.

Comment: you're gonna laught but std::cout is not recognized and printf crashed when I want to display the message alert ! My computer is trying to kill me :p

Comment: /!\ The answer is "COM:1". I couldn't answer the question because the question is closed now

Comment: @Mr.Starck - Ah, glad you got it working!

Comment: LOL. I had resolved this days ago but I had forgotten to resolve the topic :p